# Customized DataGridView with RowTemplate gives cast error when using in a Form

Tags: c#

I have created a Custom DataGridView by inheriting the Windows.Forms.DataGridView. I also have created a custom DataGridViewRow by inheriting Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRow. then i used MyDataGridViewRow as the RowTemplate of MyDataGridView. every things worked fine. but when i add MyDataGridView to a Form it'll generate properties in Form Designer File which belongs MyDataGridViewRow but since RowTemplate is a DataGridViewRow, file won't compile.

i have manually cast RowTemplate to MyDataGridRow to correct the error. but since this codes are auto generated by visual studio they'll change to the original format.

here's my current code snippet

```
public class MyDataGridView : DataGridView, IMyInterface
{
    public string LuName{get; set;}

    public MyDataGridView ()
    {
        this.RowTemplate = new MyDataGridViewRow();
    }
    ...
}

public class MyDataGridViewRow : DataGridViewRow, IMyInterface2
{
    public string RowName{get; set;}

    public MyDataGridViewRow ()
    {

    }
    ...
}
```

part of Form's Designers code:

```
partial class Form4
{
    ...
    #region Windows Form Designer generated code
    this.myDataGridView1.RowTemplate.RowName= null;  // here's the error generated line
    #endregion
    ...
}
```

what am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

just found a solution for my problem.

i have override the RowTemplate Property in MyDataGridView class

```
public class MyDataGridView : DataGridView, IMyInterface
{
    public string LuName{get; set;}

    public MyDataGridView ()
    {
        this.RowTemplate = new MyDataGridViewRow();
    }

    //Soution is override the RowTemplate Property By MyDataGridViewRow

    public new MyDataGridViewRow RowTemplate
    {
        get
        {
            return (MyDataGridViewRow)base.RowTemplate;
        }
        set
        {
            base.RowTemplate = value;
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: I was in the exact same situation as you and your fix worked flawlessly! Thanks!